# Can an object accept different types for the same parameter in R?

Tags: r

Is it possible to have an object accept multiple types for the same parameter in R?

Say I want to create an object called `taxpayer` with and attribute `id`. One taxpayer may be identified by `1234` and the other by `Smith, John`. How could I accommodate for the fact that there are multiple types that could go in the `id` field?

I recognize that I could just make the parameter a `character` field and put in `1234` as a string and convert thereafter, but wanted to ask in case there was a work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has dynamic typing. The thing you are asking about is the default behavior.  If you send in a number, it will treat it as a number.  If you send in a character, it will treat it as a string.

Here is an example:

```
# Define taxpayer class
taxpayer <- function(id) {
  
  # Create new structure of class "taxpayer"
  t <- structure(list(), class = c("taxpayer", "list"))
  
  # Assign ID attribute
  t$id <- id
  
          
  return(t)
}

# Instantiate taxpayer with character ID
t1 <- taxpayer("Smith, John") 
t1
# $id
# [1] "Smith, John"
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "taxpayer" "list"

# Check class
class(t1$id)
# [1] "character"

# Instantiate taxpayer with numeric ID
t2 <- taxpayer(1234)  
t2
# $id
# [1] 1234
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "taxpayer" "list" 

# Check class
class(t2$id)
# [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: As a follow-up: when using the setClass function, how can I have it so the parameter can accept any object type? For example ```setClass("taxpayer", slots=list(id = "character"))``. Is there something different between the `setClass` function I have been using and your `structure` generation?

Comment: There is a difference.  What I did is S3 and setClass is S4.  So you are talking about S4?  OK.  Let me investigate.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer was for an S3 style class.  For an S4 style class, you can use the "ANY" type specifier, which will take any data type.  Here is the same example as above modified for S4:

```
# Define taxpayer class
taxpayer <- setClass("taxpayer", slots = c(id = "ANY")) 

# Instantiate taxpayer with character ID
t1 <- taxpayer(id = "Smith, John") 
t1
# An object of class "taxpayer"
# Slot "id":
#   [1] "Smith, John"

# Check class
class(t1@id)
# [1] "character"

# Instantiate taxpayer with numeric ID
t2 <- taxpayer(id = 1234)  
t2
# An object of class "taxpayer"
# Slot "id":
#   [1] 1234

# Check class
class(t2@id)
# [1] "numeric"
```